# Can I cast an array of POD which has floats to float*?

Tags: c++, arrays, containers

Consider the following:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Vec2
{
  float m_x;
  float m_y;
};

vector<Vec2> myArray;

int main()
{
  myArray.resize(100);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    myArray[i].m_x = (float)(i);
    myArray[i].m_y = (float)(i);
  }

  float* raw;
  raw = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&(myArray[0]));
}
```

Is `raw` guaranteed to have 200 contiguous floats with the correct values? That is, does the standard guarantee this?

**EDIT**: If the above is guaranteed, and if `Vec2` has some functions (non-virtual) and a constructor, is the guarantee still there?

> **NOTE:** I realize this is dangerous, in my particular case I have no
>   choice as I am working with a 3rd party library.

Comment: A nice question for language lawyers :)

Comment: If this works, wouldn't `float* raw = &(myArray[0].m_x)` do the same without casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I realize this is dangerous, in my particular case I have no choice as I am working with a 3rd party library.

You may add compile time check of structure size:

[live demo](http://ideone.com/LZJ4cp)

```
struct Vec2
{
    float a;
    float b;
};

int main()
{
        int assert_s[ sizeof(Vec2) == 2*sizeof(float) ? 1 : -1 ];
}
```

It would increase your confidence of your approach (which is still unsafe due to reinterpret_cast, as mentioned).

---

> raw = reinterpret_cast(&(myArray[0]));

**ISO C++98** 9.2/17:

> A pointer to a POD struct object, suitably converted using a **reinterpret_cast**, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. —end note ]

---

And finally, runtime check of corresponding addresses would make such solution rather safe. It can be done during unit-tests or even at every start of program (on small test array).

Putting it all together:

[live demo](http://ideone.com/3AHK0v)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
struct Vec2
{
    float a;
    float b;
};

int main()
{
    int assert_s[ sizeof(Vec2) == 2*sizeof(float) ? 1 : -1 ];
    typedef vector<Vec2> Vector;
    Vector v(32);
    float *first=static_cast<float*>(static_cast<void*>(&v[0]));
    for(Vector::size_type i,size=v.size();i!=size;++i)
    {
        assert((first+i*2) == (&(v[i].a)));
        assert((first+i*2+1) == (&(v[i].b)));
    }
    assert(false != false);
}
```

Comment: C++11 has `static_assert` which is better suited for this purpose.

Comment: I know this. And also there is BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT. But code above will work on C++98 compilers, without any additional libraries.

Comment: I really like C++11, but unfortunaly can't use it at all places.

Comment: The question is tagged C++ so you can use C++11 because C++ is C++11 at the moment of asking. If you want C++03, tag the question as C++03.

Comment: @Zoidberg'-- "If you want C++03", Do you know intention of OP? Are you sure that he meant C++11 only? assert_s trick works in all C++ ISO, including C++11

Comment: That was my mistake by not tagging it C++03, however, I have a static assert implementation so this answer works for me.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not safe, because the compiler is free to insert padding between or after the two `float`s in the structure, and so the `float`s of the structure may not be contiguous.

If you still want to try it, you can add compile time checks to add more surety that it will work:

```
static_assert(sizeof(Vec2) == sizeof(float) * 2, "Vec2 struct is too big!");
static_assert(offsetof(Vec2, b) == sizeof(float), "Vec2::b at the wrong offset!");
```

Comment: IMHO, second check (offsetof) is not required after first one. POD struct members have acceseding order in memory.

Answer (score -1):

The only guarantee that a `reinterpret_cast` gives is, that you get the original object when you `reinterpret_cast` the casted object back to the original data type.

Especially, `raw` is not guaranteed to have 200 contiguous floats with the correct values.

Comment: No, I don't think so. As Axel commented, the example could be given with no casts at all with `float* raw = &(myArray[0].m_x)`. `reinterpret_cast` is irrelevant.

Comment: But the example wasn't given with no casts at all.